# Android WebView to load website with TextKit Fonts

Tags: android, fonts, webview, typekit

I have developed a web application using Android WebView.
It is supposed to load my website which is using Typekit Fonts.
The problem is my web application is not able to open the site with the actual Fonts, however the Google Chrome or the Android default Browser is able to do that successfully.

Is it that TextKit Fonts are not supported in Android WebView?
Is there a way I can make Android WebView to load a website using TypeKit Fonts?

Thanks in advance

Sumit

Comment: Hey do u have font file that you want to use for webview , i mean to say .ttf file?

Comment: typeKit fonts are special fonts which are dynamically loaded. They r not available in .ttf format but other formats which are not recognised by Android.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way..

```
First pust your font file(.ttf) in assest folder.
Crate one css file in assest folder like(weblayout.css)

weblayout.css:
-------------
@font-face { 
font-family: 'customfont'; 
src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/Helvetica_LT_55_Roman_0.ttf'); /* but this does */
}

body {
font-family: 'customfont';
}


And load webview_content in webview like this:

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                    sb.append("<HTML><HEAD><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"weblayout.css\" /></HEAD><body>");
                                    String str = YOUR_WEBVIEW_CONTENT_STRING;
                                    str = str.replaceAll("<iframe width=\"[0-9]*", "<iframe width=\"100\\%");
                                    str = str.replaceAll("<img[\\w]*", "<img height=\"auto\" style=\"max-width:100\\%\";");
                                    sb.append(str);
                                    sb.append("</body></HTML>");
                                    webFull.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```